# Ramda 'is' to vanila js

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

Hi im confuse how ramda really work, I got this code and im not sure really how it work
https://ramdajs.com/docs/#is

```
const render = curry(
  (renderer, value) => is(Function, renderer) && renderer(value)
);
```

I just need to understand the easy way to convert `is(Function, renderer`) to Vanilla JS.
I started to make a check if its string, number and object, but the check only use 'string' type not `Function`

Comment: `typeof renderer === 'function'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ramda is open source. You can see [the implementation](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/master/source/is.js).

> ```
> function is(Ctor, val) {
>   return val instanceof Ctor ||
>     val != null && (
>       val.constructor === Ctor ||
>       (Ctor.name === 'Object' && typeof val === 'object'));
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

this function allows you to safely invoke `renderer` only if it is really a function. I assume that in the original developer mind there was the possibility of it being either undefined or not a function.

```
const render = curry(
  (renderer, value) => is(Function, renderer) && renderer(value)
);
```

their vanilla equivalent would be:

```
const render = (renderer = () => {}, value = null) => renderer(value);
// or
const render = (renderer, value) => renderer?.(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `is` in many of my programs -

```js
const is = (T, t) =>
  t?.constructor === T
 
console.log(is(Array, 1)) // false
console.log(is(Array, null)) // false
console.log(is(Array, {a: 1})) // false
console.log(is(Array, [2])) // true

console.log(is(Object, 1)) // false
console.log(is(Object, undefined)) // false
console.log(is(Object, [1,2])) // false
console.log(is(Object, {a:1})) // true

console.log(is(Number, 1)) // true
console.log(is(Number, NaN)) // true
console.log(is(Number, undefined)) // false
console.log(is(Number, [3])) // false
console.log(is(Number, x => x + 1)) // false

console.log(is(Function, x => x + 1)) // true
console.log(is(RegExp, /foo/g)) // true
console.log(is(String, "hello")) // true
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```